# JavaScript Speech to Text on Android (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, typescript, speech-recognition, web-deployment

I have set up speech to text on a search bar that I've build and it works fine on my computer on Chrome.
I understand that this API isn't supported on all modern browsers yet, and so if it detects it not supported by the browser it removed the little microphone icon I have set up for the speech to be captured.

But when I try to capture speech on my Android phone, it doesn't seem to work. The Chrome is supported just doesn't do anything. I've given Chrome permissions to the microphone and have tested on two separate phones still no luck.

```js
/**
 * Search utility that converts speech to text.
 * @param {HTMLButtonElement} micButton - Mic button.
 * @param {HTMLInputElement} searchInput - Search input area.
 */
const speech_to_text = (
  micButton: HTMLButtonElement,
  searchInput: HTMLInputElement,
  submitButton: HTMLButtonElement
) => {
  const SpeechRecognition =
    window.SpeechRecognition || (<any>window).webkitSpeechRecognition;

  // Handle edge case where the speech recognition is not supported.
  if (!SpeechRecognition) {
    micButton.remove();
    submitButton.style.marginLeft = "2rem";
    return;
  }
  const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = false;
  recognition.lang = "en-GB";
  recognition.interimResults = true;
  recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

  micButton.onclick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    recognition.start();
  };

  recognition.onresult = (event: SpeechRecognitionEvent) => {
    searchInput.value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
  };

  recognition.onspeechend = () => {
    recognition.stop();
    submitButton.disabled = false;
  };
};

export default speech_to_text;
```

My code seems to be OK, just can't figure out why it doesn't work on Android.
Been digging around a bit but haven't come across anything useful.

Yeelp!

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I did, yes ( to be honest, I completely forgot I even posted this.)